# Trying to use asp.net C# stringbuilder to create multiple rows on CSV file

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, stringbuilder

Really struggling to find an answer on this, so apologies if repeat question that I may have overlooked.  I've got a table that pulls multiple rows through from the database.  Each row has a unique ID, and a checkbox. Users can check as many checkboxes as they need and then click a button to generate a CSV file with each of these rows on them.  Each checkbox adds the row ID to a text box, separated by a comma (ie. 146, 147, 148 etc) - I'm then splitting this as a string in the back end.  But whilst I can get a response.write to show the records, I can't seem to get my stringbuidler to generate anything on the CSV file bar the very first line I've checked.  I would have thought my 'foreach' would have helped, but it seems I thought wrong...

Any advice offered would be very greatly appreciated!

```
protected void DownloadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] downloads = TxtDownloads.Text.Substring(1).Split(new char[] { ',' });

        foreach(string downloadItem in downloads)
        {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append("SchemeCode, SchemeCodeDescr, OwningCompany, PrimaryManagingCompany, ManagingCompany,RentAccountManagment\n");

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spR_CSVDownload", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", downloadItem);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    string entry = "\"" + reader["SchemeCode"].ToString() + "\",";
                    entry += "\"" + reader["SchemeCodeDescr"].ToString() + "\",";
                    entry += "\"" + reader["OwningCompany"].ToString() + "\",";
                    entry += "\"" + reader["PrimaryManagingCompany"].ToString() + "\",";
                    entry += "\"" + reader["ManagingCompany"].ToString() + "\",";
                    entry += "\"" + reader["RentAccountManagment"].ToString() + "\",";


                    builder.Append(entry);


                }
            }

        }
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=download.csv");
        Response.Write(builder.ToString());
        Response.End(); 

    }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.  I do not get the part about the stringbuilder generating "anything on the CSV file bar the very first line I've checked."  But my suggestion from the get-go is that you do not need to use a string builder.  Instead, why not do the response.clear... and response writes inside the innermost if{}.  Instead of adding to a string and then sending that string to the response, why not just output your data straight to the response?

Comment: And I do not see anywhere that you are adding a `NewLine` to the output.

Comment: and, what `foreach` are you talking about.  I do not see one.

Comment: Why not use a specialized library? https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion...

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spR_CSVDownload", con))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", downloadItem);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=download.csv");

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Response.Write("\"" + reader["SchemeCode"].ToString() + "\",");
        Response.Write("\"" + reader["SchemeCodeDescr"].ToString() + "\",");
        Response.Write("\"" + reader["OwningCompany"].ToString() + "\",");
        Response.Write("\"" + reader["PrimaryManagingCompany"].ToString() + "\",");
        Response.Write("\"" + reader["ManagingCompany"].ToString() + "\",");
        Response.Write("\"" + reader["RentAccountManagment"].ToString() + "\",");
        Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
    }

    Response.End(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some playing around, finally managed to resolve the issue.  Two problems with my original code - first was that I was setting the stringbuilder after the 'foreach' statement (needs to be before); second schoolboy error was ending my 'reader.read' statement on a comma, instead of '\n' (so the reader knew when to set a new line).  Corrected code below works perfectly.

```
protected void DownloadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] downloads = TxtDownloads.Text.Substring(1).Split(new char[] { ',' });
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append("SchemeCode, SchemeCodeDescr, OwningCompany, PrimaryManagingCompany, ManagingCompany,RentAccountManagment\n");

        foreach (string downloadItem in downloads)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spR_CSVDownload", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", downloadItem);
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        reader.Read();
                        string entry = "\"" + reader["SchemeCode"].ToString() + "\",";
                        entry += "\"" + reader["SchemeCodeDescr"].ToString() + "\",";
                        entry += "\"" + reader["OwningCompany"].ToString() + "\",";
                        entry += "\"" + reader["PrimaryManagingCompany"].ToString() + "\",";
                        entry += "\"" + reader["ManagingCompany"].ToString() + "\",";
                        entry += "\"" + reader["RentAccountManagment"].ToString() + "\"\n";

                        builder.Append(entry);
                    }
                    else { builder.Append("no item found for this one " + downloadItem + "\n");  }
                }

            }
        }
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=download.csv");
        Response.Write(builder.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }   
}
```